# Spring test application

Tags: spring

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:170)
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:247)
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:62)
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:141)
    at spring.context@6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at app01/com.soft.test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 8 more
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjaAu.jpg)

Run a test application in spring

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.